# What is best practice to pass binary data between WebWorker and main thread?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

To my knowledge you can only pass a string or a object which can be seralize as JSON.

Then what is the best way to pass some image files between workers and main page if I am using WebWorker to download them in the background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> you can only pass a string or a object which can be seralize as JSON.

Your premise is wrong. You can pass every kind of object that is supported by the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm), this can for example be circular-linked data which cannot be represented as JSON. You also can pass ArrayBuffers, ArrayBufferViews, PixelDataArrays, Blobs etc, all the data types that are not known to [JSON](http://json.org/).

The second parameter of the [`postMessage` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage) of Workers does even allow you to *transfer* binary data (such as ArrayBuffers) directly to the worker - it won't even copy anything, though it will *neuter* the reference that you have.